# Lambda + Apply to get two new columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

I have df looks like:

```
Name                 Item
A,D,B,B,C,C      I1,I2,I3,I1,I2
X,Y,Z,Z,Z            I4,I1,I1,I88,I4
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Name            Item         Unique_Name  Unique_Item Count_Unique_name  Count_Unique_Item
A,D,B,B,C,C  I1,I2,I3,I1,I2    A,B,C,D      I1,I2,I3         4             3             
X,Y,Z,Z,Z   I4,I1,I1,I88,I4    X,Y,Z       I4,I1,I88         3             4
```

**Code:**

```
new_items_df['Unique_Name'] = new_items_df['Name'].apply(lambda x: set(x.lower().split(",")))
new_items_df['Unique_Item'] = new_items_df['Item'].apply(lambda x: set(x.lower().split(",")))
new_items_df['Count_Unique_Name'] = new_items_df['Unique_Modifier'].apply(lambda x: len(x))
new_items_df['Count_Unique_Item'] = new_items_df['Unique_Item'].apply(lambda x: len(x))
```

The above code works fine but I am doing same operation and running the same code twice. When I am trying to merge the 1st two lines of code like below:

```
new_items_df[['Unique_Name','Unique_Item']] = new_items_df[['Name','Item']].apply(lambda x: set(x.str.lower().str.split(",")),axis =1)
```

> TypeError: ("unhashable type: 'list'", 'occurred at index 0')

I tried to use `.unique()`also, tried converting that as a list by using `[]`, but nothing seems to work, I am getting one error or another

**Summarize:**

So, Can I get a help in combining my 4 lines of code to 1 line ?

Comment: How did `D` arrive at the output?

Comment: Yes, Edited it now

Comment: I think you can remove axis =1 in apply

Comment: Its always better to write a function for operations like these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can working with scalars with [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
c = ['Name','Item']
#python 3.6+ solution
c1 = [f'Unique_{x}' for x in c]
c2 = [f'Count_Unique_{x}' for x in c]
#python bellow 3.6
#c1 = ['Unique_{}'.format(x) for x in c]
#c2 = ['Count_Unique_{}'.format(x) for x in c]

new_items_df[c1] = new_items_df[c].applymap(lambda x: set(x.lower().split(",")))
new_items_df[c2] = new_items_df[c1].applymap(len)

print (new_items_df)
              Name             Item   Unique_Name    Unique_Item  \
0  A,A,A,B,B,B,C,D   I1,I2,I3,I1,I2  {c, b, d, a}   {i1, i2, i3}   
1        X,Y,Z,Z,Z  I4,I1,I1,I88,I4     {y, x, z}  {i1, i4, i88}   

   Count_Unique_Name  Count_Unique_Item  
0                  4                  3  
1                  3                  3
```

Comment: Thanks...Can we also combine Line 1 and Line 2 of your code and get it all done in 1 line ?

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - I think not, because second `len` is count from row above - from `new_items_df[c1]`

Answer (score 2):

use `merge` with `lambda` as follows

```
df1 = df.merge(df.apply(lambda row: extractRow(row), axis=1), left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

complete example is

```
import pandas as pd

def extractRow(row):
    nameUnique = set(row['Name'].split(","))
    itemUnique = set(row['Item'].split(","))
    return pd.Series({
        'Unique_Name' : ','.join(nameUnique),
        'Unique_Item' : ','.join(itemUnique),
        'Count_Unique_name' : len(nameUnique),
        'Count_Unique_Item' : len(itemUnique)
    })

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name' : ('A,D,B,B,C,C', 'X,Y,Z,Z,Z'),
    'Item' : ('I1,I2,I3,I1,I2', 'I4,I1,I1,I88,I4')
})

df1 = df.merge(df.apply(lambda row: extractRow(row), axis=1), left_index=True, right_index=True)

print(df1)
```